# Prove cancellation law using peano axioms.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms, peano-axioms, formal-proofs

Using Peano axioms, prove

$∀x∀y∀z(x+y=x+z→y=z)$.

I have been stuck on it for some time, could someone please give a proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

Since from previous posts I know you are working with a set of Peano axioms that recursively define addition and multiplication over the right operand, it will be much easier to prove the right-cancellation law:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (y + x = z + x \rightarrow y = z)$

You prove this fairly easily by induction over $x$

So then to prove your original theorem, you would need commutation:

$\forall x \forall y \: x+y = y+x$

which itself can be proven using induction.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:  Prove the formula $\forall x\forall y\forall z(y + x = z + x \longrightarrow\ y = z)$ in Pure Arithmetic (Domain of quantification is $\omega$---the set of all natural numbers  (Here, 0 is a natural number)

Proof  By Mathematical Induction (on x).  Let m and n be natural numbers which are arbitrarily fixed.   Define a subset ${\cal{S}}$ of natural numbers as follows:
$${\cal{S}}\ =\ \bigl\{x\ \in\ \omega: m\ +\ x\ = n\ + x\ \longrightarrow\ m = n\bigr\}$$

Prove that $0\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$:  Observe that $0\ \in\ \omega$ (means $0$ is a natural number) and that $m + 0 = m$ and $n\ +\ 0 =\ n$.  Hence $m\ +\ 0\ =\ n\ +\ 0\  \longrightarrow\ m =\ n$, which proves that $0\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$.
Now suppose that $t\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$ which is to say that the following conjunction $$(t\ \in\ \omega)\ \ \&\ \ \ (m\ +\ t\ =\ n\ +\ t\ \longrightarrow\ m =\ n)\ \ \  \ \hbox{is true}.$$We shall then show that $t^+$ (the immediate successor of $t$) belongs to ${\cal{S}}$, i.e., we must prove the conjunction:
$$(t^+\ \in\ \omega)\ \ \&\ \ m\ +\ t^+\ =\ n\ +\ t^+\ \longrightarrow\ m\ =\ n$$
The first conjunct---$t^+\ \in\ \omega$ follows from the fact that $\omega$ is an inductive set containing $t$ as an element.  To prove the second conjunct; consider the expression $\ \ m\ +\ t^+$.
$$\eqalign{m\ +\ t^+\ &=\ (m\ +\ t)^+\cr&=\ (n\ +\ t)^+\cr&=\ n\ +\ t^+\cr}$$So, we have established that $0\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$ and $t^+\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$ whenever $t\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$.  Hence, ${\cal{S}}$ is an "Inductive" set of natural numbers and as such, ${\cal{S}}$ is all of $\omega$---the set of all natural numbers (which is included in every inductive set).                                  QED

Note:  It is assumed that you are familiar with the Principle of Induction and the Inductive definition of Addition ($+$) on the set of all natural numbers, etc.

Peano Axioms

PA1   0 is a natural number.

PA2   If n is a natural number, then there is another natural number $n^+$ (called the {\bf immediate successor of $n$})

PA3   $0$ is not the immediate successor of any natural number.

PA4   If $m^+\ =\ n^+$, then $m =\ n$.

PA5   If $\ \ {\cal{S}}\ \subseteq\ \omega$ is such that $0\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$ and $x^+\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$ whenever $x\ \in\ {\cal{S}}$, then ${\cal{S}}\ =\ \omega$ (Induction Principle).

$x^+\ :=\ x\ +\ 1$ (the successor operation)

$A_x(y)\ :=\ x\ +\ y$  (Given by the Recursion Theorem)

$A_x(0)\ := x\ +\ 0\ = x$

$A_x(y^+)\ =\ (A_x(y))^+$

$A_x:\ \omega\ \to\ \omega$ (is the function whose (unique) existence is given by the Recursion Theorem where $X\ =\ \omega$, $a\ =\ 0$ and the generating function $g$ is the successor function and $f$ is $A_x$ )

Comment: Axioms:  0 is a natural number