# How to prove that in the natural numbers "if $a = b$ then $a + c = b + d$ if and only if $c = d$" using Peano Axioms?

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

I want to prove using the **Peano axioms** that in the natural numbers if $a = b$ then $a + c = b + d$ if and only if $c = d$ preferably by induction.

Comment: Check out Landau's book "Foundations of Analysis". You'll be sick of induction by the time you finish it (and it's very short too: 120 pages or so) but it's worth reading once.

Comment: If you assume that the usual properties of addition (recursively defined) are consequences of the Peano axioms, the result is a simple consequence of these properties.

Comment: @GabrielCorso Have you already shown that $0 + a = a$?

Comment: Related post [prove-cancellation-law-using-peano-axioms](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203171/prove-cancellation-law-using-peano-axioms)

Answer (score 1):

Once you assume $a = b$, then showing $c = d \rightarrow a + c = b + d$ is just a matter of using the $=$-rules.

The more interesting part is showing $a + c = b + d \rightarrow c = d$. Since $a = b$, that reduces to showing that $b + c = b + d \rightarrow c = d$, and to show that, you need to use Induction over $b$.

For the base case, this requires proving that $0 + a = a$ for any $a$, which you can do by induction itself. But assuming you have that: $0 + c = 0 + d \rightarrow c = d$ Check

Step: For this, you'll need that (AdditionLeftRecursion) $s(a) + b = s(a + b)$ for any $a$ and $b$, which again can be proven fairly easily by induction itself. But once you have that:

Assume (inductive hypothesis) $b + c = b + d \rightarrow c =d$. Then:

$s(b) + c = s(b) + d \Rightarrow$ (AdditionLeftRecusion)

$s(b + c) = s(b + d)\Rightarrow$ (Peano 4)

$b + s(c) = b + s(d) \Rightarrow$ (Inductive Hypothesis)

$s(c) = s(d) \Rightarrow$ (Peano 2)

$c = d$

Comment: @GabrielCorso Great!  Glad I could help!